# Server refused to allocate pty, Globalscape Secure FTP server on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp

I'm attempting to SSH to GlobalSCAPE Secure FTP Server.
The server is running Windows 2003 and GloablSCAPE Secure FTP Server 3.3.1.

My client is running Vista SP2 and putty 0.60.0.0.

I recieve the following message after correctly entering my username and password.

```
login as: greg
GlobalSCAPE Secure FTP Servergreg@192.168.104.2's password:
Server refused to allocate pty
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Is the globalscape ftp server designed to support only scp/sftp?  ssh is typically for interactive sessions while scp/sftp have a specific subset of the ssh protocol that is designed to support transfering files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris said, Globalscape is just an SFTP server, not a general SSH server. It won't accept connections from ssh clients. [See this knowledgebase article](http://kb.globalscape.com/article.aspx?id=10038).